# Find First Name Last Name from EMail address like Slack

Tags: email, parsing

When you invite people on slack by entering the Email Address it parses and gets the First and Second Name.

Is there any service which they are using to get this done?

Comment: The contacts you are entering likely already have Slack accounts. This is how Slack is displaying their first and last name.

Comment: @YWCAHello nope. doesnt work that way :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fullcontact is offering API which does exactly that. Have a look here: https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/

Comment: To expand on that, using FullContact you could take one of two approaches: 1) Query the [Name Deducer API](https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/name/#name-deducer) to parse out the first and last names, or query the [Person API](https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/person/) to bring back a name they've used on a social network. It all depends on what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/intuit/email-decomposer is a python package used to extract names from email addresses.